# Clean output of a panda data extraction deleting unnamed index column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, row, extract, data-cleaning

I have a dataset which have extracted a row under condition in column 'Description'. This is first few rows to show how data look like.

[image]

I have extracted a row whith the condition below:

```
ATL_ID=airport_codes[airport_codes['Description'].str.contains('Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta ')]
```

It successfully finds the row. Now, I need to extract the value under 'Code' I use this code:

```
ATL_ID.loc[:,'Code']
```

and output is:
373    10397
Name: Code, dtype: int64

I dnt want anything else in the output except 10397. 373 is the row index and the rest is additional description which I dnt want. How I can get one number for the 'Code'?

Thanks

Comment: can you add the data as text rather than an image please

Comment: Try to add `.values[0]` at the end of a `loc` statement.